# Is there a way to reload the main template of {{> yield}}

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

For some reason, I want to reload the main template specified by {{> yield}}

Is this possible in IronRouter?

Thanks!

Comment: By "reload" you mean "rerender", right?

Comment: @apendua, Yes, just rerender, or re-run, make the previous rendered template destroyed, and re-create the Template and render into the main section.

Comment: Anyone can help with an answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the entire page, you can use pure JavaScript to reload the current page:

```
document.location.reload(true);
```

Iron:Router is not necessary

Comment: Though i don't have this question now, but I don't think `document.location.reload(true);` is the answer. Optionally, we can use `Blaze.render` and `Blaze.remove` to implement.